# Where can I get free New Zealand and Melbourne geodata?

Tags: qgis, data

I have just installed QGIS. Do any forum users know where I could download or access files and maps for 1) New Zealand, and/or 2) Melbourne/Victoria, Australia. Preferably it would be good to know where free material is.

Comment: What type of data are you looking for?

Comment: "freeware" isn't a good description. You are looking for no-cost, or liberally licensed, or out-of-copyright, or some other description. freeware is really a software term, and data isn't the same.

Answer (score 4):

For New Zealand  [LINZ](http://www.linz.govt.nz/topography) has all Topo maps in Geotiff formats as well as the vector data. You can then convert them as needed - Almost all data from LDS is provided under a New Zealand Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 (BY) license. This means you can use, reuse and share data as much as you like as long as you acknowledge LINZ as the original source of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Bjørn Sandvik's [blog](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/) has an excellent collection of NZ map data links. I'd particularly suggest review of [http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/09/getting-free-data-in-new-zealand.htm](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/09/getting-free-data-in-new-zealand.html)

Answer (score 1):

Geoscience Australia is a great resource for free australian gis data

http://www.ga.gov.au/map/national/

They also release their data through a WMS service which you can access easily through QGIS

http://www.ga.gov.au/wms/getmap?dataset=national

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers will give you a good set of road map and physical data. Just use the plugin in QGIS.

Comment: do you mean openstreetmap?

Comment: So I mean the Openlayers Plugin which gives you OpenSteetMap data, thanks Iant