# Is it possible to display filtered results on OpenStreetMap?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, new-zealand

is it possible to goto [www.openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org) and do a search for a place like Auckland (New Zealand) or Melbourne (Australia) -but- only show [Cities](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:place=city) or [Neighbourhoods](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:place=neighbourhood) or Suburbs?

I understand that it's possible to use filter tags to filter results .. but does this work on the main website? or is it only used for downloading data.

if it's for downloading data .. can someone please link to some information about how to do the following

- Neighbourhoods in NZ
- Cities in NZ

NOTE: This is related to these ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/where-can-i-find-shapefiles-for-new-zealand-cities-and-suburbs-neighbourhoods#comment46209_34368) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34270/where-can-i-get-free-new-zealand-and-melbourne-geodata)) previously asked GIS questions.

Comment: You might get a better answer on the very SE-like [OpenStreetMap Help Forum](https://help.openstreetmap.org/ "OpenStreetMap Help Forum").

Answer (score 1):

Nominatim the Geocoder used by osm website supports [special clause](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/FAQ), which makes query like above possible.